# Get CRM exception to insert into SQL Azure db from sandbox db

Tags: javascript, exception, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I am practicing Dynamics CRM 2015 Online.  I actually built and ETLd the backend to 2011 On-Premise (on a previous project); so none-the-less practicing on CRM 2015 on-line is a bit of a jump.  I purchased a sandbox (not much data, having a hard time with MS getting back to me).  I also have SQL Azure.  Basically, I cannot for the life of me find address to extract the exception data (or any data for that matter) from the sandbox CRM db to extract data from to load to my Azure DB.

Scenario:  I wrote some very basic js; js works fine.  However, I implemented some js on a field that doesn't exist (bc I knew it would fail and I really want to insert exceptions in my Azure db--please don't ask for js script bc it works and is irrelevant).

**EDIT:**

In 2011 On-Premise I knew [Server].[db].dbo.[table] address but cannot find address to access db that 2015 sandbox sits on.

**END EDIT**

May someone advise on grabbing the Exception so that I can insert in my Azure db.  Thanks!

Comment: In CRM OnLine it is not possible to get direct access to the CRM database. What do you mean by "grabbing the Exception"? Do you want to store exception trace data in an Azure database?

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen ^precisely; I was afraid that I didn't have access to the db...you confirmed it, but yeah  I want to insert the exceptions that arise into the SQL Azure db.

Comment: Why not create a CRM entity to hold your exception data and then write to it (create a new record with the exception info) when an error occurs?

Comment: Dynamics CRM 2015 Update 1 introduced built-in plugin tracing. (See System Settings, Customization tab.) In previous versions it is not easy to add custom tracing, because in an error situation all changes will be rolled back by the system, including trace records that may have been created. You can only circumvent this behaviour by creating in your plugin an `IOrganizationService` instance through a new created `OrganizationServiceProxy` object.